# display buttons broken, how to turn on display from windows

Tags: windows, macos, display, power

So, my philips bdm3270 have broken touch controls and I was controlling it with SmartControl utility that lets me put screen in to standby while watching movie on projector, but yesterday I accidentally hit "turn off screen" instead of "stand by" and now I'm unable to turn it on. I tried to connect second screen and mirror screens, but whole power control in SmartControl is grayed out. I tried nircmd, but no luck - it only wakes up screen from standby... Any ideas would be very helpful! thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to use the power switch near mains connection - or disconnecting it from power source.

Comment: Yes, tried both, it does not power on.

Comment: If it doesn't turn on, it might be hardware.

Comment: I don't think so, it worked fine before I turned it off with SmartControl sw... I just hoped for some sw trickery that can turn od display...